# Can the "Do you want to run this application" prompt be avoided with ClickOnce?

Tags: clickonce

We would like to deploy an application via ClickOnce but you really do need to click twice. I.e. once on the link - at least one more time on the "Do you want to run this application" dialog (the first time).

Can some kind of trust be created (via Group Policy or otherwise) on certain PCs so that the user never gets asked any questions. I.e. we've already verified that the application is trusted etc just take this URL and it starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it can be installed without that prompt. ClickOnce applications are run from the internet zone, and it is Internet Explorer that is prompting you. It can't install software w/o asking the user if they want to. Firefox downloads the .application file and you have to double-click on it to run it. It's just like downloading any software from the internet and running it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is possible. You do need "Trusted Publisher" and "Trusted Root" as indicated by Tidjani. That answer led me to this article (linked below) - which explains using ClickOnce with certificates fully and clearly. I now have a popup-free ClickOnce app. It finally really is one click.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996418.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, i found out that you can avoid this message by signing your application with a certificate. Then, the same certificate must be installed on your client machine in these two locations: "Trusted Publishers" and "Trusted Root Certification Authorities".

It worked well for my XBAP applications in Full Trust mode.